# Dock icons keep reappearing and trackpad settings keep reverting on restarting my macbook

Tags: macos, mac

I removed Mission control, mail client, launchpad and other items from my dock, and set natural scrolling off, as well as 'tap to click' Everytime I restart however, the items come back on the dock and the settings revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting these files:

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist`

If that doesn't work, you could also try editing them directly with for example `defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool false`.

Comment: Thank you. Turns out there was 2 conflicting users sharing UID or something, deleting one did the trick.